# Is exercise on a full stomach more effective at burning Calories?

Tags: physical-fitness

[This article](http://www.fitnessmagazine.com/workout/lose-weight/burn-fat/burn-more-calories/?page=0) makes a number of interesting claims about health and fitness, but I wanted to focus on this one:

> In one *International Journal of Sports Nutrition and Exercise Metabolism* study, exercisers who ate breakfast before working enjoyed significantly higher VO2 (a measure of energy expenditure) and fat-burn rates compared to those who hadn't eaten breakfast before exercising.

1. Can this be traced to a particular study which is not objectively problematic (e.g. retracted, published in a disreputable journal, rejected by a subsequent meta-study, etc.)?
2. Is the study causal, or just correlational (i.e. did they passively observe, or actively assign people to control and treatment groups)?
3. More generally, does the study support the claim that **eating before exercising is more effective at burning calories and/or fat than eating after exercising**?

Comment: @Dawn: I am specifically concerned with the boldfaced claim: If you're going to eat before or after your workout, do you burn more from eating before or from eating after?

Comment: Presumably this is the study they are referring to: [Exercising Fasting or Fed to Enhance Fat Loss? Influence of
Food Intake on Respiratory Ratio and Excess Postexercise
Oxygen Consumption After a Bout of Endurance Training](http://www.fabiozonin.it/public/07Paoli_J3606%20IJSNEM_20100023%2048-54.pdf)

Comment: That result doesn't sound very interesting. A body that is exercising + digesting food is bound to burn more calories than one that is only exercising.

Comment: @flimzy or, a body that isn't hungry can do better workouts. But still, there is no interestingness threshold for questions here, so it doesn't matter how boring anyone thinks this question is.

Comment: A [relevant video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2d0vYkWX0Y), but she lacks references. Essentially she says that your insulin levels are lower before you eat, but increases after you eat (decreasing your natural Growth Hormone [GH] levels). Since insulin helps to store body fat, and displaces your GH, exercising will be less "effective".